# Will the SQL Server default dateformat/language affect my DateTime object toString rendering?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

Is there any relation between the SQL Server  default date format/language and  a DateTime object rendered as a String in a asp.net application?

Can the default SqlServer date format affect the DateTime strings from my reports I generated? The asp.net application is using EntityFramework to get data.

Comment: Dates don't have formats. They may have timezones, but formats are only for UI purposes.

Comment: I think the date would be interpreted fine from database to asp.net application. However, the 'regional' setting of your computer does have an impact when rendering DateTime object into string (unless you format it explicitly).

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server stores [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) type as binary. It uses 8 bytes. First 4 byte is for the date and second 4 byte is for the time.

This type is [mapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/sql-clr-type-mapping) with [System.DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime) in CLR side and this `System.DateTime` does *not* have format either. It just have date and time values. It is based on [`Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks) wihch is the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 in the Gregorian calendar.

As you can see, both are actually kind of numeric values.

On the other hand, the "format" concept *only* applies when you get their *textual* (aka string) representations which is usually done with `DateTime.ToString` method in C# side and `Format` method in SQL Server side.

So, if you choose right data type (see: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)) for your `System.DateTime` values in your SQL Server (usually done with `datetime` or `datetime2`), no, your SQL Server default date format/language does not affect the format that generated for your reports.

When you feed your reports directly with your `DateTime` value, the `ToString()` method will called automatically (if there is no custom format etc..) and this method uses standard [The `"G"` Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-general-date-long-time-g-format-specifier) with your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) settings.

For beginners, it is *really* important to understand the difference between a DateTime instance and their string representations (format).

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx):

> DateTime toString method converts the value of the current DateTime
>   object to its equivalent string representation using the specified
>   format and the formatting conventions of the current culture.

Which means, no it will not. Rendering will be affected by application culture setting - so however you will handle it it will show date time accordingly.

Current culture (as on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) again)

> The culture is a property of the executing thread. This read-only
>   property is equivalent to retrieving the CultureInfo object returned
>   by the Thread.CurrentCulture property. When a thread is started, its
>   culture is initially determined by calling the Windows
>   GetUserDefaultLocaleName function.

In case of ASP.NET most likely this would be a setting derived from user's operating system culture setting (I took long shortcut here). However this might be [overridden](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) in web.config (or elsewhere):

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />
```

Comment: ok, let's go even further: where is "current culture" coming from?

Comment: I already seen the answer to my question, it comes from "regional" OS setting

Comment: @AngJobs - yes, when it is not set up differently. I would recommend you to get familiar with details on MSDN to avoid surprises and have control over settings.